# GnuPG: how add user ID as single command without having to use Key Edit menu

Tags: gnupg, command-line-arguments

Is there a command that can be given to GnuPG: to add user ID **without** having to go through the  *Key Edit* menu.

We need to be able to add and delete User IDs from inside a Python program.
It would be wonderful if there was a way to do that with one single line.
Does anyone know how to do that?

Thank you in advance.
Vivarto

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any way to do that without editing the key and even if there was, you still wouldn't be able to get it down to one line because modification of a key requires verification (entering your passphrase and interactive answering of questions that you really want to do it).

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping for another answer, however I have to live with facts, not dreams:)

Comment: I'd say "no problem" except clearly it is. ;) Theoretically a **lot** of coding might enable you to get part of the way there (you'd still need to deal with the passphrase), but it would involve reimplementing large chunks of the OpenPGP spec and if you're not already subscribed to the IETF WG list then you really don't know how much pain that would involve. I'm not going to say don't try, but I will say that it ain't no shortcut.